# jQuery animation left in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-animate

Have some problems with used `.animate {left:"+= 190"}`. In Safari this code works not good.

Symptoms:

The `'div'` container back to zero position and animate to `190`. In result I have some *jumpy* effects.

The container code here:

```
  .task-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: $width-tasker;
    height: 100px;
    top: 80px;
    left: calc(50% - 350px);
    transition: left 1s ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why make animation with jQuery ? Just add a class with jQuery and animate it in css, no ? It's more performant

Comment: Hmm, thx  for idea. But I am very interested, why my first version isn't work:(

Comment: Try to post a snippet for see what is wrong

Comment: @Cyril Beeckman  right